# Loop an if function in a very large table. Too slow

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have a very large table. 700,000 rows. to get the information i need, i need to add a column that receives a simple if or function.
the problem is, it is so slow. it calculated only 7000 rows in 60 seconds. i need 700,000...
Using a regular excel function it works in a few seconds. there must be a way to do this with VBA.
Thanks!!

Here is the code i have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 6) = "C & O"

     'count rows
    Dim count As Long
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            count = count + 1
       Else: Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'Fill in coulmn F
    For K = 2 To count
        If (Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 651 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 652 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 653 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 805 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 806 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 808 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 804 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 807 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 809 Or Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) = 810) Then
            Sheet1.Cells(K, 6) = "Oversize"
        Else
            Sheet1.Cells(K, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(K, 5)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use the worksheet function in VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Simple optimization could be to read Cell content only once (it is quite slow):

```
Dim k4
For K = 2 To count
    k4 = Sheet1.Cells(K, 4) 
    If (k4 = 651 Or k4 = 652 Or k4 = 653 Or k4 = 805 Or k4 = 806 Or k4 = 808 Or k4 = 804 Or k4 = 807 Or k4 = 809 Or k4 = 810) Then
        Sheet1.Cells(K, 6) = "Oversize"
    Else
        Sheet1.Cells(K, 6) = Sheet1.Cells(K, 5)
    End If
Next
```

If this is not enough then convertion to array might be necassary.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the following way:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    If (cell.Value >= 651 And cell.Value <= 653) Or _
        (cell.Value >= 804 And cell.Value <= 810) Then
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Oversize"
    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    End If

Next cell
```

This ran 1 sec with 37000 rows of data.

Comment: Thanks for answer! works on shorter file, but still too slow for the full 700,000...

Answer (score 1):

500K (half-a-million) rows in 0.96 seconds on a Surface 4 tablet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim a As Long, arr As Variant
    Dim ca As Long

    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    With Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)
        .Cells(1, 6) = "C & O"
        'you want count to be this,
        ca = .Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).Row
        'it is more typically called like this,
        ca = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'grab 2-D array of values from columns D:F
        arr = .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(ca, "F")).Value2

        'loop through array
        For a = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            Select Case arr(a, 1)
                Case 651, 652, 653, 804, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 810
                    arr(a, 2) = "oversize"
                Case Else
                    arr(a, 2) = arr(a, 3)
            End Select
        Next a

        'put the modified 2-D array back into the worksheet
        .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(ca, "F")).Value2 = arr
    End With

    appTGGL

End Sub

Public Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
        .EnableEvents = bTGGL
        .DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
        .AutoRecover.Enabled = bTGGL   'no interruptions with an auto-save
        .Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .StatusBar = vbNullString
    End With
    Debug.Print Timer
End Sub
```

I have include a 'helper' column that temporarily suspends various application environment settings in order to speed up the procedure.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer! i have used this code and it looks like it should work, only that the result is "oversize" in the correct places in coulumn "E" rather that "F". and it does not fill in the "Case else" with column E. think its just a matter of which column was chosen for the arrays.

Comment: My apologies; I seem to have misunderstood your original code. `arr(a, 2)` is column E, `arr(a, 3)` is column F. Hope you can make modifications.

Comment: Found the problem. a bit of a mix between arr (a,2/3) the output should be arr(a,3). i fixed it and it works perfect on my test sheet. but on the full 700,000 i get an out of memory error... any ideas?

Comment: The debug shows the error here:
arr = .Range(.Cells(1, "D"), .Cells(ca, "F")).Value2